# FTP error when doing file transfer

Tags: ftp

I'm running vsftpd version 3.0.2 over FTPeS, and I'm having a bit of trouble with file transfers.  It seems to work fine when I'm on the LAN, but not from an external IP address.  I have the control port and data ports open on my server's software firewall and my router's firewall.  When I'm using the service from an external IP address, it seems like sometimes a file transfer will complete, but it times out and I always get the client error:

> "426 Failure writing network stream".

I've tried several clients.  I'm thinking there is some sort of data sabotage either at the router or some server policy; maybe because I'm using passive ftp?  Suggestions?

Comment: The only suggestion I can have regarding FTP and FTPS is to switch to SFTP prompltly.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you need to open range of 'passive' ports on external router. Plenty of info on the inet, for example:

http://www.theserverpages.com/articles/servers/cpanel/tweaks/Getting_passive_FTP_connections_to_work_through_a_firewall_properly.html

Also I believe you need to specify external IP in ftp server config.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I do have the data ports open on my router.

I didn't mention much about my server config, but I did specify my public IP address.  I'm able to connect and sort of transfer files.  I just get the above error when I do.